# Do saunas burn significantly more calories than just sitting idly?

Tags: medical-science, physical-fitness

There are a bunch of sites claiming this, with the most disparate theories: that [saunas directly melt fat](http://tuberose.com/Sweating.html), that [saunas burn calories because your body needs to maintain the normal temperature](http://www.sharecare.com/question/do-you-burn-calories-by-sitting-in-sauna), that [saunas increase your metabolism](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/benefits-sauna), that [they make your heart work harder](http://www.saunaaa.com/sauna-burns-calories.php)...

I also found a ton of suspicious pages like [this one](http://caloriecount.about.com/forums/weight-loss/burn-extra-calories-steam-room).

While there are a million theories, has anyone measured if any extra calories are burnt at all? If so, does sitting idly in a sauna burn significantly more calories than sitting idly elsewhere?

Comment: **Note**: this question was asked as part of the "[topic of the week](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1371)" initiative to raise our questions per day stat. Please contribute some great questions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > Sauna makes your heart work harder

Sauna definitely increases heart rate ([[1]](http://www.colorado.edu/eeb/courses/1230jbasey/abstracts%202008/14.htm) and [[2]](http://www.scielo.br/pdf/rbme/v12n4/en_10.pdf))

Does sauna makes you burn calories the same as exercise ? No.

> The most accurate method of measuring calorie burn is through VO2
>   testing
>   ... 
>   Combustion, which turns the fuel you receive from food into
>   energy, needs oxygen. Because there is a direct relationship between
>   how much oxygen you use and how much energy you burn, by measuring the
>   oxygen to carbon dioxide exchange through VO2 testing, you will get a
>   fairly precise gauge of how many calories you're burning.

[eHow "How Heart Rate Monitors Calculate Calories Burned"](http://www.ehow.com/how-does_5700177_heart-monitors-calculate-calories-burned.html)

[This study](http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/jpts/8/1/25/_pdf) has show following results:

VO2 on exercise (ml/min) 1269,4 +/- 426,1
VO2 on suana (ml/min)  236,9 +/- 42,7

Oxygen update in suana was much less then during exercise.

What about sauna and sitting ?

Let's say sitting requires 1 [MET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent), then for 120 kg person would intake about 120 ml / min. 
Walking for the same person (120 kg) would be 120 kg * 3 ml / min kg = 360 ml / min

So, sauna makes your body burn more calories than sitting, it's can't be compared to exercises.

Comment: You lost me in the last part. Do you burn more calories than sitting? How many more?

Comment: @Sklivvz **Sitting: ~120 ml/min, Sauna: ~240 ml/min,** Walking: ~360 ml/min, Exercise: ~1270 ml/min. Calorie burn depends on body statistics.

Comment: But it's quite possible the 120 ml/min increase in VO2 value doesn't do much for the calorie burn. I'm not familiar enough with the topic to do the calculations. There are [some online calculators](http://www.shapesense.com/fitness-exercise/calculators/heart-rate-based-calorie-burn-calculator.aspx) for this type of stuff but it seems they don't take the values in the form provided in this answer.