# Do saunas assist in sustainable weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do saunas burn significantly more calories than just sitting idly?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8502/do-saunas-burn-significantly-more-calories-than-just-sitting-idly)

While I'm not disputing the fact that sitting in a hot room will cause weight loss through the loss of fluids due to sweating, I am skeptical of claims ([1](http://www.sunlighten.com/infrared-weight-loss.html), [2](http://www.ehow.com/how_2105350_lose-weight-sauna.html)) that frequent use of the sauna can lead to sustainable weight loss such as that through the loss of excess fat in the body. As such, is there any evidence that the regular use of a sauna actually leads to sustainable weight loss?